# Access 2013 help enter data by a button

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a database which is divided into two positions,
one in my office and one for students with touchscreen.

A student needs to report any faults or suggest efficiencies.  In order for things to not be too complicated.  I want their form to be made from buttons that once clicked puts a value to the table and continues to the next field.

Example: "location" = a, b, c, etc. "Sub-location" = a, b, c, etc.
I tried several codes that failed.

Comment: Please share your failing code with us. People tend to help people more likely who show their effort. Also it is easier to help on defective code, than to write code for other people from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it. if you want to add new record from a button or image wan the table is closed you can use this code

```
   Dim rstCategories As Recordset
    Set rstCategories = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Name:="table name",Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)

    With rstCategories

        .AddNew
        ![failed name] = "value you want to insert"
        .Update


    End With
```

tnx me helping me :)